# Doing math on sql count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do some mathematical operations on the results of two queries.

This is my query:

```
select (x.failed/y.total) * 100 as failure_rate, x.failed, y.total
from
(
select count(*) as failed from status where cast(ins As Date) = cast(getDate() As Date) and fail_flg = 'Y'
) x
join 
(
select count(*) as total from status where cast(ins As Date) = cast(getDate() As Date)
) y on 1=1
```

This is the result im getting back:

```
failure_rate    failed  total
0               1       2
```

I should have a failure rate of 50, where am I going wrong?  I have a gut suspicion the problem is somewhere in my `count(*)`....do I need to cast this as a number somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does integer arithmetic.  Convert to a non-integer number.  I do this as:

```
select (x.failed * 100.0 /y.total) as failure_rate, x.failed, y.total
```

I should add that I would write the query without subqueries:

```
select sum(case when fail_flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as failed,
       count(*) as total,
       avg(case when fail_flag = 'Y' then 100.0 else 0 end) as failed_rate
from status
where cast(ins As Date) = cast(getDate() As Date) ;
```

Normally, I would recommend not doing the `cast()` or any other function on a column.  That precludes the use of indexes.  However, SQL Server makes an exception for `cast(as date)`, so your code is still index-safe (or "sargable" in the lingo of SQL Server).

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, I wasn't even close on where the underlying issue was.  And thank you for the revised query!  Will mark this as answer when it lets me.